# Утилита BCP. Создание формат-файла

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

На msdn написано, что если таблица имеет имя `myTestFormatFiles`, находится в схеме `dbo`, в БД с именем `AdventureWorks2012`, то команда выглядит так:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012..MyTestFormatFiles format nul -c -t, -f myTestFormatFiles.Fmt -T
```

У меня вот такой случай:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался сделать вот так:

```
bcp TestDB..test_table format nul -c -t, -f d:\format.fmt -T
```

Но вот что выходит:

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could no
t open a connection to SQL Server [2].
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-
specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Serve
r is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL S
erver is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Se
rver Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
```

Я почти уверен, что тут что-то не так с `TestDB..test_table` :) Но не знаю, что именно.

Как должна выглядеть команда в моём случае?

Comment: Вы напрасно уверены. Сообщение ихним по белому говорит, что не установлено соединение с сервером. Так что до передачи серверу имени таблицы (и уж тем более - до проверки, правильно ли это имя) дело ещё не дошло.

Comment: @Akina, я так думаю, потому что имя сервера должно как то быть указано в TestDB..test_table. Иначе откуда ему вообще ясно, что за сервер?

Comment: _откуда ему вообще ясно, что за сервер?_ При отсутствии в параметрах запуска указания сервера утилита будет обращаться к дефолтному инстансу локалхоста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спросил на английском стеке. Нужно добавить `-S k551l\sqlexpress` к команде.